# Sauce connect times out when running tests on Circle CI

Tags: circleci, saucelabs

My NightWatch tests have started to timeout on Circle CI

I am getting this message

> while [ ! -e ~/sauce_is_ready ]; do sleep 1; done
>
> command while [ ! -e ~/sauce_is_ready ]; do sleep 1; done took more
>   than    10 minutes since last output

[Timeout message on Circle CI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoETz.png)

The tests are timing out every time I try to rerun the tests.

Im not sure how to see the error logs given by sauce labs.

On the saucelabs dash board I can see the tunnel is never being created.

Any suggestions about potential causes or ways to see the error logs, would be greatly appreciate.